# Setting gridview column background dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, background-color, sencha-architect

I'm using Ext JS 4.0 and the Sencha Architect 4.1

I want to set the column background of each column based on a value of the corresponding record.

I know how to change the cell background using a renderer. But I don't know how to do this for the whole column because I don't want to set a renderer for each cell in my gridview.

Is there a way to set the background for the whole column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it this way:

In the Site.css I added a style like this

```
.custom-row .x-grid-cell {
    background-color: #ffe2e2;
}
```

and in my `Ext.grid.View` I added the `getRowClass` method like this

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
        var isConditionMatching = ....

        if(isConditionMatching ){
            return 'custom-row';
        }
    },
```

Comment: Your question specifically asked about setting the styles for particular columns... "Is there a way to set the background for the whole column?"

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tdCls` config on the column and then write a css rule to apply the styles as appropriate.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-tdCls

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed? I'm quite new to Ext Js and Javascript and don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Pretty much as I said. Assign a `tdCls`, write some css: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2431

Comment: Thank you for the sample. The problem is: I want to set the background based on a property of the record which is assigned to the row. And as far as I know I can not put this logic in a css file.

Comment: Then write a renderer.

Comment: That's why I asked this question. At the moment I have a renderer for each cell and I thought maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Those are basically the only 2 options. You could write a css rule dynamically and use the `tdCls` option, it depends on your use case.

Comment: Can you give me a short example how to set the `tdCls` dynamically? Do I have to use the `getRowClass` method?

Comment: Solveit it using the `getRowClass` method. Thank you for the help